# COMPATIBLE_HOST vs COMPATIBLE_MACHINE in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to build a particular recipe only for ARM architectures. Reading from mega manual, it says

> A recipe is considered incompatible with the currently configured
>   machine when either or both the COMPATIBLE_MACHINE variable and
>   COMPATIBLE_HOST variables specify compatibility with a machine other
>   than that of the current machine or host.

Which one should i pick up COMPATIBLE_MACHINE or COMPATIBLE_HOST in my recipe. What's the difference between them

Again From mega-manual regarding COMPATIBLE_HOST:

> A regular expression that resolves to one or more hosts (when the
>   recipe is native) or one or more targets (when the recipe is
>   non-native) with which a recipe is compatible.

How do we differentiate between native and non-native recipes?

Comment: `native` is a program that should run on your build machine, `non-native` is a program that will be run on target machine (generally cross-compiled). You probably want `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE` variable.

Comment: How can we find this out by looking at a recipe. Whether it is native recipe or non-native recipe

Comment: A pure native recipe ends with `-native` suffix (and inherit native). A standard recipe can also be used in native architecture using `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"`.